# C++ date output

Tags: c++, date, output

If i ask the user to input a date 
and he entered "16 then 5 then 2010"
how can I display it this way

```
16/5/10
```

I only did it this way

```
cout<<day<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;
```

but the output appears this way

> 16/5/2010

Comment: http://m.xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just print the year modulo 100. For example,

```
int yr1 = 1973;
int yr2 = 2010;
std::cout << (yr1%100) << std::endl; // prints 73
std::cout << (yr2%100) << std::endl; // prints 10
```